# disable static to fixed navbar script on mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've been working on a navbar/header for my website. When you scroll 100px past the logo, the navbar changes to fixed and sits at the top.

This is all well and good, but on smaller viewports I don't want it to do this, As I have the logo hidden, and the navbar permanently fixed to the top.

The problem is when you scroll down the it still runs the script and hides the navbar and then it reappears. I made a futile attempt of adding display: block to the css when viewed at a max-width of 768px, which didn't do much. How would I go about not running this script on smaller viewports, or is there a better solution?

[Here's a jsfiddle, try it in mobile view and scroll down.](https://jsfiddle.net/gx25ospo/8/)

Here's the code I'm working with

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var nav = $('#custom-bootstrap-menu');
    var body = $('body');
    var top = 100;
    var logo = $('div#navlogo');
    if ($(window).scrollTop() >= top) {

        nav.addClass('navbar-fixed-top');
        body.addClass('padding-fifty');
        logo.css('display', 'block');

    } else {
        nav.removeClass('navbar-fixed-top');
        body.removeClass('padding-fifty');
        logo.css('display', 'none');

    }
});
```

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit: Updated the fiddle. Does this help?

The idea is to clone a navigation bar for your mobile view and show it only in small screens and hide the other nav bar.

https://jsfiddle.net/6gyc6aeq/

**JS**

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
var nav = $('#custom-bootstrap-menu');
var body = $('body');
var top = 100;
var logo = $('div#navlogo');
if ($(window).scrollTop() >= top) {

    nav.addClass('navbar-fixed-top');
    body.addClass('padding-fifty');


} else {
    nav.removeClass('navbar-fixed-top');
    body.removeClass('padding-fifty');


}
});

$("#mobile-only").html($("#custom-bootstrap-menu").html());
```

**HTML**

```
 <body>

<div id="logo">
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <h1>CHEEZ-IT</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">

        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>    





<!-- Static navbar -->
<nav id="custom-bootstrap-menu" class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <div id="navlogo">            
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">CHEEZ-IT!</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">About Us <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Who are Cheez-it's</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Credentials</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#contact">Our Services</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Industries <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Cheeze-it Solar</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Cheeze-it Infrastructure</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Cheeze-it Harvest</a></li>                
          </ul>
        </li>

        <li><a href="#contact">Partners</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
  </div>
</nav>
 <nav id="mobile-only" class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">

 </nav>


<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">

        <h2>CONTENT IS GRAND</h2>
        <h2>CONTENT IS GRAND</h2>
        <h2>CONTENT IS GRAND</h2>
        <h2>CONTENT IS GRAND</h2>
        <h2>CONTENT IS GRAND</h2>
        <h2>CONTENT IS GRAND</h2>
        <h2>CONTENT IS GRAND</h2>
        <h2>CONTENT IS GRAND</h2>
        <h2>CONTENT IS GRAND</h2>
        <h2>CONTENT IS GRAND</h2>
        <h2>CONTENT IS GRAND</h2>
        <h2>CONTENT IS GRAND</h2>            
        <h2>CONTENT IS GRAND</h2>
        <h2>CONTENT IS GRAND</h2>
        <h2>CONTENT IS GRAND, MAN</h2>


    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#logo {
height: 100px;
}

.padding-fifty {
  padding-top: 50px;
}

.navbar-static-top #navlogo {
  display: none;
 }

 #custom-bootstrap-menu{
   display :block;   
 }
  #mobile-only{
      display:none;  
  }

 #custom-bootstrap-menu.navbar-fixed-top #navlogo{
        display:block;
 }

@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
body{
 padding-top: 50px;

}

 #logo {
 display: none;
}

#navlogo {
display: block;
}
 #custom-bootstrap-menu{
   display :none;   
 }
 #mobile-only{
      display:block;  
  }





 }
```

Comment: I like what you're doing here but the nav is no longer fixed to the top when on mobile

Comment: Did you have any other ideas?

Comment: Awesome. Glad I could help.

Comment: I just noticed one problem, the responsive menu doesn't seem to work anymore, i'll have a crack at it